# Background PHP Process with shell_exec() As Part of WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, background-process

I'm trying to run a background PHP process with `shell_exec()` as a part of WordPress plugin.

This is the sample.

```
/* Plugin Name: Sample Background Process */

add_action('init', 'Sample_Background_Process');    
function Sample_Background_Process() {
    $file = __DIR__ . '/log.html';
    $current = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . ': accessed<br />';
    file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

It creates a log in the plugin folder and whenever a page gets access it appends some text to it.

Then, I added this line, `shell_exec('php "' . ABSPATH . '/index.php" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');`. So a background process should access the page and run the function which appends text to the log file. But it doesn't seem to be doing it. I expect one page load produces two lines in the log file. But it only adds one line, which means a background process is not run or WordPress does not do anything if it is called like this.

```
add_action('init', 'Sample_Background_Process');    
function Sample_Background_Process() {
    $file = __DIR__ . '/log.html';
    $current = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . ': accessed<br />';
    file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND);
    shell_exec('php "' . ABSPATH . '/index.php" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

The path, `php` in `shell_exec()` is altered by the path to php.exe in my actual script since I'm testing on Windows server. It runs fine in other PHP scripts.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure safe mode is disabled on the Windows server?

Comment: `if( ini_get('safe_mode') )` returns false.

Comment: Try turning error reporting on and running just that single line on it's own. This should give you some clue as to what's going on. You may also want to print out the string you're passing to `shell_exec` and executing it manually.

Comment: It's strange that the line worked in other scripts. I have to figure it out. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I tested it again and found `/dev/null 2>/dev/null` doesn't work at all in Windows. I thought it would have worked but as I view the other test scripts that I have created before, they were using `2>&1`. So, thanks, all became clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK ( as far as i know ) /dev/null doesn't exist in windows
just use NUL... for example

```
shell_exec('php "' . ABSPATH . '/index.php" > NUL &');
```

Comment: It seems to work. Thanks. And I realized that it creates an infinite process loop.

Comment: well... the infinite loop isn't what i excepted :)

Comment: using shell_exec in windows is a bad idea